# magento 1.7.0.2 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'irtto.catalog_product_flat_5'

Tags: mysql, magento

I manually refresh the index Product_Flat_Data, but it doesn't succeed. I get the following exceptions:

```
[root@www shell]# /www/wdlinux/php/bin/php -f indexer.php -- -reindex catalog_product_flat
Product Flat Data index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'irtto.catalog_product_flat_5' (errno: 150)' in /home/www/irtto/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/www/irtto/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/www/irtto/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/www/irtto/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/www/irtto/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/www/irtto/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#5 /home/www/irtto/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#6 /home/www/irtto/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2039): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('CREATE TABLE `c...')
#7 /home/www/irtto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(702): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->createTable(Object(Varien_Db_Ddl_Table))
#8 /home/www/irtto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1390): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(5)
#9 /home/www/irtto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#10 /home/www/irtto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(336): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#11 /home/www/irtto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#12 /home/www/irtto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#13 /home/www/irtto/public_html/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#14 /home/www/irtto/public_html/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#15 {main}
```

Next exception

```
'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'irtto.catalog_product_flat_5' (errno: 150)' in /home/www/irtto/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home/www/irtto/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/www/irtto/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/www/irtto/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/www/irtto/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#4 /home/www/irtto/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `c...', Array)
#5 /home/www/irtto/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2039): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('CREATE TABLE `c...')
#6 /home/www/irtto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(702): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->createTable(Object(Varien_Db_Ddl_Table))
#7 /home/www/irtto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1390): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(5)
#8 /home/www/irtto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#9 /home/www/irtto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(336): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#10 /home/www/irtto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#11 /home/www/irtto/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /home/www/irtto/public_html/shell/indexer.php(158): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /home/www/irtto/public_html/shell/indexer.php(198): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#14 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql user you have used in `indexer.php` (/www/wdlinux/php/bin/php -f indexer.php) do not have write privileges to database. Give that user write privileges.

Comment: This user is the system root, refresh other indexes properly.magento local.xml user database is with write permission.

Comment: do you have sufficient disk space, check like $df -h

Comment: thank you，the first step I confirm disk space, there are a lot of free disk space.

Comment: /dev/mapper/vg_centos6-lv_root
                       50G   25G   25G  51% /
tmpfs                 1.8G  228K  1.8G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   36M  424M   8% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_centos6-lv_home
                      144G   57G   80G  42% /home

Comment: I still doubt that the user in used in indexer.php have write permission. Login to MySQL with same user and try to create dummy table. do like 1) $mysql -u<that_user> -p<password>, 2) $user <your database> 3) CREATE TABLE ...... (full syntax)

Comment: Prior to this, all is well, and then I create a new store view, on this error occurs。

Comment: Please try as I said manually, if it is permission issue, you'll know (it is debug process)

Comment: I checked the permissions on this question myself root user access to the database, copy the catalog_product_flat_1' structure, then the command to refresh the index to solve this problem. Your answer was a great help for me, thank you!

Comment: So after the operation. Log_customer Login table  log to stay in the moment, there is no longer any increase, how to deal with?